# Indentation problem with \cvlistdoubleitem inside a list

Tags: moderncv

I am trying to finish my CV with `moderncv` and I am running into Trouble.

I am trying to embed a `\cvlistdoubleitem` within a list but the indentation is monstrous and the items are left cut.

Here is an example of the code I am using:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

 \moderncvtheme[black]{casual}           
 \usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
 \usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}                       
 \usepackage[scale=0.8, top=2cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.5cm}     




 \firstname{xx}
 \familyname{xxx}
 \title{xx}
 \address{xx}
 \mobile{xx}
 \phone{xxx}
 \email{xx}

 \makeatletter
 \renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
 \makeatother
 \renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-}


 \begin{document}
 \maketitle

 \section{Section1}

 \subsection{Subsection}
 \cvline{Forschungsthemen}{
 \begin{itemize}
 \item blabla
 \item blabla
 \end{itemize}
 }
 \cvline{Verwendete Methoden}{
 \begin{itemize}
 \item Polymerisationsmethoden \newline
 \cvlistdoubleitem{Anionisch}{ringöffnend}
 \cvlistdoubleitem{Kationisch}{Vernetzung}
 \cvlistdoubleitem{Kupplungsreaktionen}{Polymeranalohe Umsetzung}
 \item Charakterisierung \newline
 \cvlistdoubleitem{Kernspinresonanzspektroskopie}{Infrarotspektroskopie}
 \cvlistdoubleitem{Rasterelektronenmikropskopie}{Transmissionselektronenmikroskopie}
 \cvlistdoubleitem{Lichtstreuung}{}
 \end{itemize}
 }





 \vskip\baselineskip
 here, \today\\ % Aktuelles Datum und Stadt
 \end{document}
```

My questions is: how can I reduce the indentation of `\cvdoublelistitem`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be slightly easier for us to help you if your code snippet were compilable. It should start in `\docuentclass` and contain a `\begin{document}...\end{document}` environment. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)

Comment: Thanks for the MWE. There as a closing curly brace missing so the MWE would not compile. I have added it. Please always test a MWE before posting to make sure it compiles and shows the issue at hand.

Answer (score 3):

I think that in your case the best would be to use `\cvcolumn` instead of `\cvlistdoubleitem`.

Please see this MWE (I added section references, line 54 ff):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}

 \moderncvtheme[black]{casual}           
 \usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
 \usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}                       
 \usepackage[scale=0.8, top=2cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.5cm}     




 \firstname{xx}
 \familyname{xxx}
 \title{xx}
 \address{xx}
 \mobile{xx}
 \phone{xxx}
 \email{xx}

 \makeatletter
 \renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
 \makeatother
 \renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-}


 \begin{document}
 \maketitle

 \section{Section1}

 \subsection{Subsection}
 \cvline{Forschungsthemen}{
 \begin{itemize}
 \item blabla
 \item blabla
 \end{itemize}
 }
 \cvline{Verwendete Methoden}{
 \begin{itemize}
 \item Polymerisationsmethoden \newline
 \cvlistdoubleitem{Anionisch}{ringöffnend}
 \cvlistdoubleitem{Kationisch}{Vernetzung}
 \cvlistdoubleitem{Kupplungsreaktionen}{Polymeranalohe Umsetzung}
 \item Charakterisierung \newline
 \cvlistdoubleitem{Kernspinresonanzspektroskopie}{Infrarotspektroskopie}
 \cvlistdoubleitem{Rasterelektronenmikropskopie}{Transmissionselektronenmikroskopie}
 \cvlistdoubleitem{Lichtstreuung}{}
 \end{itemize}
 }

\section{References} % <======================================
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Polymerisationsmethoden}{%
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Anionisch
      \item ringöffnend
      \item Kationisch
      \item Vernetzung
      \item Kupplungsreaktionen
      \item Polymeranalohe Umsetzung
    \end{itemize}%
  }
  \cvcolumn{Charakterisierung}{%
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Kernspinresonanzspektroskopie
      \item Infrarotspektroskopie
      \item Rasterelektronenmikropskopie
      \item Transmissionselektronenmikroskopie
      \item Lichtstreuung
    \end{itemize}%
  }
\end{cvcolumns}



 \vskip\baselineskip
 here, \today\\ % Aktuelles Datum und Stadt
 \end{document}
```

with this result:

[image]

Other possibility would be to use `\cvlistitem` instead of `\cvlistdoubleitem`? You have very long German words, and a hyphenation would not look better imo.  English words are shorter and then could `\cvlistdoubleitem` work better (the columns could be smaller).